# Error mapping a publication to a website in Topology Manager

Tags: web8, topology-manager

When running the `Add-TtmMapping` PowerShell script for a Publication with a Publication URL property of `/en` to a website with a URL defined similar to `http://example.com` I am getting this error message:

> The server-relative URL `''` of the Mapping does not match the Publication URL property

But I don't see where I can define this server-relative URL in the `Add-TtmMapping` script, where can I specify this server-relative URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Server-relative URL is a combination of WebApplication ContextUrl and Mapping RelativeUrl properties, so if you use default root web application for you mapping you can specify

```
 -RelativeUrl en
```

in `Add-TtmMapping` cmdlet

Comment: This is the correct solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to make your Publication URL (in Contebt Manager) "context-relative" (read: empty).

That is the preferred approach where the first part of the URL is managed purely in Topology Manager, instead of overlapping with the Publication URL in CM.

Comment: What you see if you do `Get-TtmMapping` is the *primary* mapped URL, but if your website has multiple base URLs, they can in principle all be used to do URL - Publication mapping. If you use the "View on site" feature in the CME, it will always use the primary mapped URL, though.

Comment: Yeah.. anyways just fixed it by setting up publication path in Publication settings and mapping the 2nd Url as the website location and it worked.